# Building GPL C program with CUDA module

Tags: cuda, makefile, nvcc

I am attempting to modify a GPL program written in C. My goal is to replace one method with a CUDA implementation, which means I need to compile with nvcc instead of gcc. I need help building the project - not implementing it (You don't need to know anything about CUDA C to help, I don't think).

This is my first time trying to change a C project of moderate complexity that involves a .configure and Makefile. Honestly, this is my first time doing anything in C in a long time, including anything involving gcc or g++, so I'm pretty lost.

I'm not super interested in learning configure and Makefiles - this is more of an experiment. I would like to see if the project implementation goes well before spending time creating a proper build script. (Not unwilling to learn as necessary, just trying to give an idea of the scope).

With that said, what are my options for building this project? I have a myriad of questions...

- I tried adding "CC=nvcc" to the configure.in file after AC_PROG_CC. This appeared to work - output from running configure and make showed nvcc as the compiler. However make failed to compile the source file with the CUDA kernel, not recognizing the CUDA specific syntax. I don't know why, was hoping this would just work.
- Is it possible to compile a source file with nvcc, and then include it at the linking step in the make process for the main program? If so, how? (This question might not make sense - I'm really rusty at this)
- What's the correct way to do this?
- Is there a quick and dirty way I could use for testing purposes?
- Is there some secret tool everyone uses to setup and understand these configure and Makefiles? This is even worse than the Apache Ant scripts I'm used to (Yeah, I'm out of my realm)

Comment: The thing you might have missed is file extensions. nvcc uses files extensions to work out what contains device code and what does not - any device code containing files must have a `.cu` extension to compile correctly.

Comment: Just curious, what are you doing in the CUDA function?

Comment: Good point about the .cu files. I will try renaming some of the source files.

Comment: I am trying to adapt [fcrackzip](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/fcrackzip.html) to execute in a CUDA kernel. It's for a school project of my choosing, hopefully that is still in bounds since it's not exactly homework.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to compile everything with nvcc.  Your guess that you can just compile your CUDA code with NVCC and leave everything else (except linking) is correct.  Here's the approach I would use to start.

1. Add a 1 new header (e.g. myCudaImplementation.h) and 1 new source file (with .cu extension, e.g. myCudaImplementation.cu). The source file contains your kernel implementation *as well as* a (host) C wrapper function that invokes the kernel with the appropriate execution configuration (aka `<<<>>>`) and arguments.  The header file contains the prototype for the C wrapper function.  Let's call that wrapper function `runCudaImplementation()`
2. I would also provide another host C function in the source file (with prototype in the header) that queries and configures the GPU devices present and returns true if it is successful, false if not.  Let's call this function `configureCudaDevice()`.
3. Now in your original C code, where you would normally call your CPU implementation you can do this.

   ```
   // must include your new header
   #include "myCudaImplementation.h"

   // at app initialization
   // store this variable somewhere you can access it later
   bool deviceConfigured = configureCudaDevice;          
   ...                             
   // then later, at run time
   if (deviceConfigured) 
       runCudaImplementation();
   else
       runCpuImplementation(); // run the original code
   ```
4. Now, since you put all your CUDA code in a new .cu file, you only have to compile that file with nvcc.  Everything else stays the same, except that you have to link in the object file that nvcc outputs.  e.g.

   ```
   nvcc -c -o myCudaImplementation.o myCudaImplementation.cu <other necessary arguments>
   ```

Then add myCudaImplementation.o to your link line (something like:)
        g++ -o myApp  myCudaImplementation.o

Now, if you have a complex app to work with that uses configure and has a complex makefile already, it may be more involved than the above, but this is the general approach.  Bottom line is you don't want to compile all of your source files with nvcc, just the .cu ones.  Use your host compiler for everything else.

I'm not expert with configure so can't really help there.  You may be able to run configure to generate a makefile, and then edit that makefile -- it won't be a general solution, but it will get you started.

Note that in some cases you may also need to separate compilation of your `.cu` files from linking them. In this case you need to use NVCC's separate compilation and linking functionality, for which [this blog post might be helpful](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/).

Comment: Great, thank you for taking the time to explain that. I can handle that approach.

Comment: Got it working. One additional step others may need to do is add extern "C" {  } around the wrapper method. This is probably obvious to linking veterans, though.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use extern "C" unless you only have C linkage (e.g. calling it from a .c file).

Comment: @harrism Is it correct to say that the source compiled with g++ can have cuda runtime API such as cudaMalloc(&p) and cudaMemcpy(p) -- but it cannot have kernel launches such as foo<<<>>>(p)?

Comment: For cuda 5.0 and later:  https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/

Comment: @user1823664 yes that's correct to say. However there is the cudaLaunch() API for launching without `<<<>>>`.