# Can I use CUDA with C++ program by G++. Or CUDA can be compiled only with GCC?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, g++, nvidia

I have not achieved stage when I will parallel my program with CUDA, but I use C++ instead C and I am worried if my program would not compiled with CUDA!

Somebody can find proof for this deal.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common question about CUDA. You can compile device code with nvcc to object file then link in using g++.

For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363827/building-gpl-c-program-with-cuda-module), for example.

Comment: Yes, like this: g++ -o app <some linker flags> nvcc_gen.o <other objects>

Comment: ONE NOTICE! I have to compile object files with command "nvcc x.o y.o".  Be aware! I compiled x.o with g++, but y.o with nvcc!!! It is cool.